# hierarchical dynamic output in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am demultiplexing sequencing reads by two sets of barcodes. First, I use a set of barcodes to demultiplex into samples, next, each sample has to be demultiplexed again using the second set of barcodes to get a number subsamples. At each of these steps, there is not really known how many files will be generated, because I do not know if all my barcodes are in the reads file. Seems like a situation to use dynamic rules. The first stage of demuxing is easy enough for my toy example where `afile.csv` is a list of names like `>prod1.fastq` with one product per line:

```
rule all:
input: dynamic("{product}.fastq")

rule demux:
input: "afile.csv"
output: dynamic("{product}.fastq")
shell: '''
        cd demux
        cat ../{input} | sed "s/>//g" | xargs touch
        cd ..
       '''
```

Now, I thought of having another rule `demux2` that, in this toy example, creates 2 files from each product. I have miserably failed trying:

```
rule all:
input: dynamic("{product2}.fastq")

rule demux:
input: "afile.csv"
output: dynamic("{product}.fastq")
shell: '''
        cd demux
        echo {input}
        cat ../{input} | sed "s/>//g" | xargs touch
        cd ..
       '''  

rule demux2:
input: dynamic("{product}.fastq")
output: dynamic("{product2}.fastq")
shell: '''
    echo {input} | sed 's/.fastq/_ITS1.fastq/g' | xargs touch
    echo {input} | sed 's/.fastq/_ITS2.fastq/g' | xargs touch
    '''
```

or, an alternative:

```
rule all:
input: dynamic("{product}_{its}.fastq")

rule demux:
input: "afile.csv"
output: dynamic("{product}.fastq")
shell: '''
        cd demux
        echo {input}
        cat ../{input} | sed "s/>//g" | xargs touch
        cd ..
       '''  

rule demux2:
input: dynamic("{product}.fastq")
output: dynamic("{product}_{its}.fastq")
shell: '''
    echo {input} | sed 's/.fastq/_ITS1.fastq/g' | xargs touch
    echo {input} | sed 's/.fastq/_ITS2.fastq/g' | xargs touch
    '''
```

Any ideas on how to solve this. In nextflow it is quite easy, but I want to do it in snakemake and it is one of the most common situations in working with sequencing data...